# Add Package Control in Sublime Text 3 through the command line

Tags: linux, scripting, installation, sublimetext3

I am trying to make a script for setting up my development environment automatically in a linux machine. One of this steps is to install `Sublime Text 3`.

Installing sublime is not a problem, but I would enjoy if I could install the package manager as well.

Is there any way to install the package manager from the command line?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The easiest way is to download https://packagecontrol.io/Package%20Control.sublime-package using `wget` or `curl`, and store it in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages`. It will then set itself up upon first starting the editor. As a bonus, if you create `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings` and populate it with the packages you want installed, everything *should* work more-or-less automatically to download and install everything. A restart is generally a good idea, but this is a good way to script the setup of a new development environment. As an example, a minimal ST3 `Package Control.sublime-settings` file is below, so you can get an idea of how it's set up:

```json
{
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "AutoFileName",
        "BracketHighlighter",
        "ExportHtml",
        "GenerateUUID",
        "HexViewer",
        "Neon Color Scheme",
        "PackageResourceViewer",
        "PlistJsonConverter",
        "Python Flake8 Lint",
        "Python Improved",
        "SideBarEnhancements",
        "SideBarGit",
        "SublimeCodeIntel",
        "SublimeREPL",
        "Tag",
        "Terminal",
        "Theme - Soda"
    ]
}
```

Good luck!